# How to populate table cell by column using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a html table [Image table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZAAG.png), and I would like to populate or fill the html table using data from database(mysql). This is the data from my database [Image Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faUgg.png). I can not think of anything to put the data into my html table per supplier name. Do you guys know how to do this? Using any of the languages such as PHP, JavaScript.

This is my actual table [Actual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVTbN.png). I already tried it myself but I only get the supplier name. This is the my code to get the supplier name. This should be the expected output [Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huOEi.png)

```
<thead>
 <tr id="tr-1">
   <th><th><th><th><th></th></th></th></th></th>

   <?php $i = 1; foreach ($supp_name as $key => $value) { ?>
      <th colspan="2" class="supplier_name_class"><input type="text" class="supplier_name" placeholder="Supplier Name" id="supplier_name-1" value="<?php echo $value->supplier_name; ?>" style="width: 300px; text-align: center;"></th>
   <?php $i++; } ?>

   </tr>
     <tr id="tr-2">
     <th>LN</th>
     <th>PR No</th>
     <th>Description</th>
     <th>Qty</th>
     <th>Unit</th>

     <?php $i = 1; foreach ($supp_name as $key => $value) { ?>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Total</th>
     <?php $i++; } ?>

   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 <?php $i = 1; foreach ($supp_dtl as $key => $value) { ?>
 <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>

 </tbody>
```

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also... jQuery isn't a language. It's just a javascript library.

Comment: Please see my updated post.

Comment: In your first loop, you're echoing data. Just do the same in the other loops? You can also remove all `$i`-variables since they're not necessary when using foreach.

Comment: I hope that is easy but in the database there are two unit_price for 1 supplier.